# CouchDB supports caching?

Tags: caching, couchdb

Does CouchDB supports caching out of the box or do I have to manually have a caching proxy in front of it like Squid?

Comment: Yes it supports the web cache (with etags), out of the box, no config needed. No it does not have a web cache.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Short answer: No.

### Long answer: Yes?

The whole philosophy of CouchDB is to think about everything that might be queried later, compute it now (when it's convenient), and store the result in an index. All data access from CouchdB comes from scanning one of these indexes, which is very fast and tends to take roughly the same amount of time regardless of the amount of data (logarithmic time actually.)

Furthermore, CouchDB does not use much memory, because it expects the operating system to cache its disk operations. The filesystem cache provides huge a huge performance benefit.

Finally, CouchDB supports all the web standards for caching, so browsers and ISPs often cache parts of it without anybody doing anything special.

I suppose my point is that for high *read* load, CouchDB often does not need a cache.
However, no, there is no out-of-the-box cache feature. One reason CouchDB uses HTTP is to allow people to use standard tools to solve their problems. Many people do use caching web proxies in front of CouchDB in production.

Answer (score 5):

It supports a form of caching via [ETags](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API?highlight=(etag)#ETags.2BAC8-Caching). (an HTTP caching mechanism)

The ETag is the same as the documents `_rev` number. You can send an `If-None-Match` header along with your `GET` request. If there is a new version, the server will send it. Otherwise, it sends back a `300 Not Modified` header, letting you know that you can keep using the revision you already have.

Comment: But I still have to have a caching proxy like Squid in front of it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Squid in this context. I guess that depends on the architecture. If you are trying to offload the workload on a single server by adding other cache nodes, you could always just have your CouchDB server replicate to other nodes to help distribute the load.

Comment: You do not need a reverse-proxy cache, but if you do it will reduce load at the expense of memory. Note also that the web-browsers will also cache, so this reverse-proxy cache will only help with the first cacheable hit of each page from each user (repeat hits will be cached in browser anyway).